# git - swap/exchange a remote branch

Tags: git, remote-branch

I have two remote branches:

1. ***feature233***
2. ***v1.9.12***.

I need to rename the 1. branch to ***v1.9.12*** and the 2. branch to ***v1.9.15*** :

1. ***feature233***  --> ***v1.9.12***
2. ***v1.9.12***  --> ***v1.9.15***

Since the new name of the 1. branch is the same as the old name of the 2. branch, is going to be any problem for the rest of the users of the remote repository?
What should they do  to have localy the new name of both branch?

Thanks!

Comment: How are the old `v1.9.12` and `feature233` related to each other? Is one the (direct or indirect) parent of the other?

Comment: yes, feature233 is an indirect parent of v1.9.12

Answer (score 0):

> Is going to be any problem for the rest of the users of the remote repository?

It might, as it changes completely the history of (what they referred to) `v1.9.12`
The users would have to reset their local branch to the new origin/v1.9.12 remote branch.

```
git fetch
git branch -f v1.9.12 origin/v1.9.12
```

They might want to create a branch where the old `v1.9.12` is on their local repo, in case they have work committed there, and want to go back to it.